# It is taking a long time to start my system from the setup CD

Tags: installation

I reformatted my laptop's hard drive because my Windows XP installation was damaged, and now I am trying to boot from the CD and install 11.10, but the installation just won't start.

I have a 2.4 GHz Intel Celeron single core processor and 240 MB of RAM, and a 40 GB hard drive in the system I want to use Ubuntu on, it is a Toshiba Sattelite A15.

Are those requirements strong enough or no?

Answer (score 0):

> The Recommended Minimum System Requirements, here, should allow even
>   someone fairly new to installing Ubuntu or Gnu&Linux to easily install
>   a usable system with enough room to be comfortable. A good "rule of
>   thumb" is that machines that could run XP, Vista, Windows 7 or x86 OS
>   X will almost always be a lot faster with Ubuntu even if they are
>   lower-spec than described below. **Simply try Ubuntu CD as a
>   [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCd) first to check the hardware works**.
>
> Ubuntu Desktop Edition
>
> - 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> - 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
> - 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive    but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)<sup>1</sup>

So based on the information above, you don't have enough ram to run Ubuntu.  For your system, I would recommend [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/), or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Recommended Minimum System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)</sup>

Comment: Including more information by posting the system requirements for both DE's would help your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your system does not meet the minimum requirements to install Ubuntu. As JoeSteiger suggests, you can try installing a more light-weight distribution, however, from looking at their minimum requirements, it looks like Lubuntu may be a better choice for your machine.

**Ubuntu:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/

> - 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> - **512 MiB RAM** (system memory)
> - 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
> - VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> - Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> - Internet access is helpful

**Xubuntu:** http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/

> To install or try Xubuntu within the Desktop/Live CD, you need 256 MB
>   of memory. Installing with the Alternative CD requires only 64 MB.
>   Once installed, it is strongly recommended to have at least 512 MB of
>   memory, but you can run with **256 MB** too.

**Lubuntu:** https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

> A Pentium II or Celeron system with **128 MB** of RAM. Desktop CD should
>   not be used to install on systems with less than 1 GB of RAM. Please
>   download the alternate ISO.